# passing constructor to function c++ without calling delete

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to call a constructor of 1 object with the constructors for other objects, and am having a problem with things deleting. The important bits of code look like the following:

```
class command {
public:
    command(const string& s) {
        x = (char*) calloc(s.size()+1, 1);
        memcpy(x, s.c_str());
    }
    ~command() {
        free(x);
    }
private:
    char* x;
}
```

this constructor mallocs a char* which needs to be freed in the destructor.

```
class pair {
public:
    pair(command comm1in, command comm2in)
    :comm1(comm1in), comm2(comm2in){};
private:
    command comm1;
    command comm2;
}
```

this one tries to set its 2 fields to the commands sent in.
I think it also calls their copy constructors (might be wrong though)

in another function, I call the constructor for pair like so

```
pair p(command("something"), command("something else"));
```

unfortunately, this has the effect of calling the destructors on the just created values and then the copy constructor in the constructor for pair.

Is there a good way to initalize comm1 and comm2 without going through the copy/delete process?
I think c++11 has rValue references and std::move but I don't know if those come into play here.

Comment: If you are in C++, don’t use malloc, use new and std::string.

Comment: @Aganju Is correct but if ever in a situation where you need to manage your own resources make sure you follow [the rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint in the constructor and destructor of `command`? Then you can note the address of the object that is being created and destroyed in each case and see if they match up, and also, how many times each is called. This may give you some insight into what is going on.

Comment: @aganju I'm using char* because i use strsep on it then pass it to execvp().

Comment: If you have a naked pointer in your class you need to follow the rule of three, because the default copy constructor and assignment operator do not do what you need which is a deep copy.  Instead you end up double deleting things.

Comment: @Schulace : `std::string::data()` exists for a reason; there's no reason to do a manual allocation here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja what I'm trying to do is avoid a copy altogether. is that possible?

Comment: @ildjarn std::string::data() returns a const char*, and I need a non-const char* so I can split it up. please answer the question instead of telling me to use a function I've already implemented. (c_str() and data() are the same)

Comment: For some reason I thought this was tagged `c++1z` rather than `c++11`, apologies. That said, I would still use `std::vector` over a manual allocation, or `std::unique_ptr` worst-case.

Comment: If you want to prevent copying, make your copy constructor and assignment operator private. It will become immediately obvious then when a copy is needed. If you weren't making a copy somewhere you wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

So I asked one of my professors about this and then played around. [This](https://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/move-semantics/) was extremely helpful.

Here is what the above code should look like if we want to avoid double-freeing the pointer x.
command:

```
class command {
public:
    command(const string& s) {
        x = (char*) calloc(s.size()+1, 1);
        strcpy(x, s.c_str());
    }
    command(command&& in): x(in.x) {
        other.x = nullptr;
    }
    ~command() {
        if(x) delete x;
    }
private:
    char* x;
}
```

pair:

```
class pair {
public:
    pair(command&& comm1in, command&& comm2in)
    :comm1(std::move(comm1in)), comm2(std::move(comm2in)){};
private:
    command comm1;
    command comm2;
}
```

calling pair's constructor looks the same

```
pair(command("something"), command("something else"));
```

Learnings:

calling the delete constructor is unavoidable, so instead we must define a move constructor for command that gives it the R-value's pointer and sets the R-value's pointer to null. (so when its destructor is called it doesn't deallocate still-pointed-to memory)

To allow objects to be moved into another object, initialize them with std::move()

Why do this?

- This allows for us to ensure that only that 1 instance of command will have the object.
- We don't have to malloc / call new and get space on the heap.
- the command is automatically deleted when pair is deleted, so we don't have to write a delete function